# Interpolation of sin(x) using Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on a homework problem for which I am supposed to make a function that interpolates sin(x) for n+1 interpolation points and compares the interpolation to the actual values of sin at those points. The problem statement asks for a function Lagrangian(x,points) that accomplishes this, although my current attempt at executing it does not use 'x' and 'points' in the loops, so I think I will have to try again (especially since my code doesn't work as is!) However, why I can't I access the items in the x_n array with an index, like x_n[k]? Additionally, is there a way to only access the 'x' values in the points array and loop over those for L_x? Finally, I think my 'error' definition is wrong, since it should also be an array of values. Is it necessary to make another for loop to compare each value in the 'error' array to 'max_error'? This is my code right now (we are executing in a GUI our professor made, so I think some of the commands are unique to that such as messages.write()):

```
def problem_6_run(problem_6_n, problem_6_m, plot, messages, **kwargs):
    n = problem_6_n.value
    m = problem_6_m.value

    messages.write('\n=== PROBLEM 6 ==========================\n')

    x_n = np.linspace(0,2*math.pi,n+1)
    y_n = np.sin(x_n)

    points = np.column_stack((x_n,y_n))

    i = 0
    k = 1
    L_x = 1.0

    def Lagrange(x, points):
        for i in n+1:
            for k in n+1:
                return L_x = (x- x_n[k] / x_n[i] - x_n[k])
            return Lagrange = y_n[i] * L_x

    error = np.sin(x) - Lagrange

    max_error = 0
    if error > max_error:
        max_error = error

    print.messages('Maximum error = &g' % max_error)

    plot.draw_lines(n+1,np.sin(x))
    plot.draw_points(m,Lagrange)
    plots.draw_points(m,error)
```

Edited:

Yes, the different things ThiefMaster mentioned are part of my (non CS) professor's environment; and yes, voithos, I'm using numpy and at this point have definitely had more practice with Matlab than Python (I guess that's obvious!). n and m are values entered by the user in the GUI; n+1 is the number of interpolation points and m is the number of points you plot against later.

Pseudocode:
Given n and m

Generate x_n a list of n evenly spaced points from 0 to 2*pi
Generate y_n a corresponding list of points for sin(x_n)

Define points, a 2D array consisting of these ordered pairs

Define Lagrange, a function of x and points

for each value in the range n+1 (this is where I would like to use points but don't know how to access those values appropriately)

evaluate y_n * (x - x_n[later index] / x_n[earlier index] - x_n[later index])

Calculate max error
Calculate error interpolation Lagrange - sin(x)

plot sin(x); plot Lagrange; plot error

Does that make sense?

Comment: Why do you accept arbitrary *kwargs* in your method if you don't use them? And why not just call the first two arguments `n` and `m`? Or is that a requirement caused by the environment you are working in? Applications written by professors (especially when they aren't CS professors) tend to do odd things sometimes :p

Comment: It looks like you're using numpy. Also, this is invalid Python; you reference your `Lagrange` function in multiple places, but it won't be evaluated unless you add parens `()`. Also, your function is returning  from two places, and assigning a value to its own reference..? This almost looks like Matlab written in Python-esque syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- You can access items in `x_n` via `x_n[k]` (to answer your question).
- Your loops `for i in n+1:` and `for k in n+1:` *only execute once each, one with `i=n+1` and one with `k=n+1`*. You need to use `for i in range(n+1)` (or `xrange`) to get the whole list of values `[0,1,2,...,n]`.
- in `error = np.sin(x) - Lagrange`: You haven't defined `x` anywhere, so this will probably result in an error. Did you mean for this to be within the `Lagrange` function? Also, you're subtracting a *function* (`Lagrange`) from a number `np.sin(x)`, which isn't going to end well.
- When you use the `return` statement in your `def Lagrange` you are exiting your function. So your loop will never loop more than once because you're returning out of the function. I think you might actually want to *store* those values instead of returning them.

Can you write some pseudocode to show what you'd like to do? e.g.:

```
Given a set of points `xs` and "interpolated" points `ys`:
For each point (x,y) in (xs,ys):
    Calculate `sin(x)`
    Calculate `sin(x)-y` being the difference between the function and y
.... etc etc
```

This will make the actual code easier for you to write, and easier for us to help you with (especially if you intellectually understand what you're trying to do, and the only problem is with converting that into python).

So : try fix up some of these points in your code, and try write some pseudocode to say what you want to do, and we'll keep helping you :)